# Not A Member sign in math mode in algorithm2e

Tags: math-mode, algorithms, algorithm2e

For the below algorithm, i get the erorr 
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
 \egroup
l.759 }

I think having another prantes in the if condition is also another problem, that I do not know how to cope with.
Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{x}
\KwResult{y}
\ForEach{Subject in Subjects}{
                \If(G(Subject, rdf:type, d ) $\notin$ T) {
                     violation = true\;
                     BREAK\;
                  }
} 
VIOLATION = false\;

\caption{Algorithm for checking}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation for `\If` is incorrect. You're using `\If(..){...}` while you should be using `\If{..}{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{x}
  \KwResult{y}
  \ForEach{Subject in Subjects}{%
    \If{G(Subject, rdf:type, d ) $\notin$ T}{%
      violation = true\;
      BREAK\;
    }
  }
  VIOLATION = false\;
  \caption{Algorithm for checking}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```